# Return to a specific block of code in my application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am fairly new to C# and currently building a simple ATM app. I am attempting to write code to return the user to the main menu according to his/her entry of the letter M. The break, continue, goto or return keywords do not seem to work in my scenario; perhaps I used them incorrectly. The statement directly below is where I would like to jump to.

```
Console.WriteLine("Select an option? \n VIEW BALANCE (B1) checking, (B2) saving \n DEPOSIT (C1) checking, (C2) saving \n WITHDRAW (W1) checking, (W2) saving");
```

I would like to jump from the line ***JUMP*** (below) within the else if statement nested within the switch statement into the section of code above. How can I achieve this? any help is appreciated...thanks!

```
switch (response)
{
    case "C1": 
        Console.WriteLine("How much would you like to deposit to your checking account?");
        string depositEntry = Console.ReadLine();
        double checkingBalance = Convert.ToInt32(depositEntry) + currentCheckingBalance;
        currentCheckingBalance += checkingBalance;
        Console.WriteLine("Your current checking balance is " + checkingBalance + "\n (X) Exit, (M) Main Menu" );

        string selection = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
        if (selection == "X")
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (selection == "M")
        {
            ***JUMP***
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your entry was invalid");
        }


        break;

    case "C2":      

        break;

    case "W1":
```

Comment: Why not simply break!

Comment: I tried a break, it returns to the beginning of the if statement block. I would like to return to the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Using a jump statement usually indicates the flow of logic is jumbled. I try to avoid any kind of jumps if necessary. The code below prints out a main menu and if the user types “x” the program will quit. If the user selects one of the other options, a message is simply printed out indicating what the user selected. After the user presses any key, the console clears and the main menu is re-displayed.

In the main menu, if the user does not type one of the selections, then the selection is ignored, the console is cleared, and the menu is reprinted. No error is displayed indicating invalid selections.

This does not require the user to type “m” to go back to the main menu. After a selection is made for Deposit/withdraw/… after the method is finished the code will automatically return to the main menu.

I am guessing this may be what you are looking for. Hope this helps.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

  string userInput = "";
  while ((userInput = GetMainSelection()) != "x") {
    switch (userInput) {
      case "c1":
        Console.WriteLine("C1 Deposit Checking method");
        break;
      case "c2":
        Console.WriteLine("C2 Deposit Savings method");
        break;
      case "b1":
        Console.WriteLine("B1 View Balance Checking method");
        break;
      case "b2":
        Console.WriteLine("B2 View Balance Savings method");
        break;
      case "w1":
        Console.WriteLine("W1 Withdraw Checking method");
        break;
      case "w2":
        Console.WriteLine("W2 withdraw Savings method");
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key to continue"); // <-- show what method was just used
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.Clear();
  }
  Console.Write("Press any key to exit the program");
  Console.ReadKey();
}

private static string GetMainSelection() {
  string userInput = "";
  while (true) {
    Console.WriteLine("Select an option? \n VIEW BALANCE (B1) checking, (B2) saving \n DEPOSIT (C1) checking, (C2) saving \n WITHDRAW (W1) checking, (W2) saving. (X) to EXit");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    if (userInput == "b1" || userInput == "b2" || userInput == "c1" || userInput == "c2" || userInput == "w1" || userInput == "w2" || userInput == "x") {
      return userInput;
    }
    else {
      Console.Clear();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Very clean and easy to interpret at my current skill level.

Answer (score 0):

Put the JUMP code in a function and return.

```
public void MainMenu() {
    // Show the main menu
}

public void Response(string response) {
    switch (response)
    {
        case "C1": 
            Console.WriteLine("How much would you like to deposit to your checking account?");
            string depositEntry = Console.ReadLine();
            double checkingBalance = Convert.ToInt32(depositEntry) + currentCheckingBalance;
            currentCheckingBalance += checkingBalance;
            Console.WriteLine("Your current checking balance is " + checkingBalance + "\n (X) Exit, (M) Main Menu" );

            string selection = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            if (selection == "X")
            {
                return;
            }
            else if (selection == "M")
            {
                ***JUMP***
                MainMenu();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your entry was invalid");
            }


            break;

        case "C2":      

            break;

        case "W1":
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the already given answer, I suggest breaking this out. Here's an example:

The `Main` method:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string input = null;

    do {
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        ParseInput(input);
    } while (input != "X");
}
```

`ParseInput`:

```
static void ParseInput(string input) {
    switch (input) {
        case "X": //from Main(), this will close the app
            return;
        case "M":
            MainMenu();
            break;
        case "C1":
            ShowAccount("C1"); //move your deposit/withdraw logic into a method and call with the selected account
            return;
        //other accounts
        default:
            break; //error message?
    }
}
```

and `MainMenu`:

```
static void MainMenu() {
    Console.WriteLine("Select an option? \n VIEW BALANCE (B1) checking, (B2) saving \n DEPOSIT (C1) checking, (C2) saving \n WITHDRAW (W1) checking, (W2) saving");
}
```

This should let you read the input in a loop and the `ParseInput` function can handle your individual cases. You may also want to call `MainMenu()` at the start, so it shows from the beginning.

It works like this:

1. Get input from the user
2. Pass the input to `ParseInput()` which decides where to go next.
3. Any functions hit in `ParseInput()` will execute, writing to the console or asking for further input
4. Once that function returns, `while (input != "X")` evaluates. If `input != "X"`, goto 1, else exit.

Comment: Thanks alot for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `goto` C# reference.

```
static void Main()
{
    int x = 200, y = 4;
    int count = 0;
    string[,] array = new string[x, y];

    // Initialize the array:
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)

        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            array[i, j] = (++count).ToString();

    // Read input:
    Console.Write("Enter the number to search for: ");

    // Input a string:
    string myNumber = Console.ReadLine();

    // Search:
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            if (array[i, j].Equals(myNumber))
            {
                goto Found;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("The number {0} was not found.", myNumber);
    goto Finish;

    Found:
        Console.WriteLine("The number {0} is found.", myNumber);

    Finish:
        Console.WriteLine("End of search.");


    // Keep the console open in debug mode.
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output for the Input 44 would be:

- Enter the number to search for: 44
- The number 44 is found.
- End of search.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx) for the MSDN reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion!